# Ajax Load - How to force load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a page and put it inside a div.

*code :*

```
 $("#test").load("page.php");
```

The problem is that **once it's loaded**, sometimes **when I re-execute** this script, it seems that the file 'page.php' is **not really reloaded**, seems that this file is keep in a cache or something like this.

It's really a problem because I have a **PHP** request inside this file it doesn't execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force not to cache it in the [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) and reset it back when not required. `.load` is just an ajax call and `cache` is defaulted to true.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The browser is caching the request. It thinks it knows the result it will get, so it doesn't send a request.

To fix this, add a dynamic `get` parameter to the end of the url. This will trick the browser into expecting something new each time.

Here's an example code:

```
$("#test").load("page.php?v=" + Math.random());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a cache problem. You could change the ajaxsetup, or do something with a random string.

The reason the caching happends is because you request the same url twice. It has allready fetched that result, so it's just gets the cache's value. The simple trick is to add someting random:

```
$("#test").load("page.php?_"+Math.random());
```

I use underscore to it because doesn't overwrite any other get values (jQuery does it about the same way)

Comment: For my own benefit, why do the other posts get upvotes, and I dont? I don't see any information which is alot better than my reply. For my future posts, what didn't I do right?